# What happens when disk space runs out?

Tags: python, diskspace, disk-io

Suppose I do:

```
with open("temp.txt", "w" as f):
    while True:
        f.write(1)
```

What shall happen when I come close to completely using up my disk space? It seems like a problem that might have been asked before, but unfortunately I didn't find anything. Thanks...

In case it matters, I'm on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the disk will be full (or when you will exhaust your quota if the filesystem supports them), the `write` will raise an IOError. If that exception is not filtered in a try block, it will terminate the script.

But bad things could happen. Most tools currently expect to have enough disk and memory, and most system implement multi-tasking. That means that if you exhaust the system disk, various system components could start to malfunction, especially if you are running under an admin account. Long story made short: avoid that unless you are experimenting on a dedicated file system...